# Combing object files generated out of C and C++ projects

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to compile two projects together to create one executable. The first project is written in C and it uses the following portion of the makefile to generate the corresponding object files.

```
obj/%.o : %.c .dirs
    $(CC) $(MKDEPEND) -w -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<
```

The second project is written in C++ and it uses the following portion of the Makefile to generate the object file.

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp .dirs
    $(CXX) $(MKDEPEND) -w -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<
```

When I try to create the final executable, I receive an "undefined reference to function" for my C objects. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
$(TARGET) : $(OOBJS) $(SUBTARGETS)
    $(CXX) -w -o $(TMP_TARGET) $(OOBJS) $(LIBS) $(LFLAGS) $(SUBTARGETS) && mv -f $(TMP_TARGET) $@
```

Comment: Do you have your C headers wrapped in `extern "C"` declarations? That is necessary so that C++ doesn't mangle the names when calling from C++ into C.

Comment: Without seeing the source code it is difficult to give exact instructions what you have to do. Create a [mre], show the code and the full error message.

Comment: Sorry for the minimal code. Yes, C headers are wrapped in extern "C" declarations. Creating a library out of the C project and linking it to the C++ project, in the end, seems to solve this issue.